# DateTime Format - Any System Datetime.now to "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss"

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program that do several things. 
Two of them is **read a date from a txt** and **rewrite a date in the same txt**.

The read of the date is a regex expression like:

```
[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1})
```

The problem is that my regex expression only works in the format 
"DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss" and its impossible to make sure my regex expression can match all system datetime formats.

So, I need to make sure my program run's in every system, regardless the system datetime.now.
For that, i thought about format every system datetime.now, at start, to the format mentioned "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss".

At the moment i have the following code:

```
Datetime currentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, when running some tests, using a system date in format "D/M/YYYY h:m:s" i get the error:

**"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."**

The problem is that if my date, for example, is "9/27/2019 04:26:46"(M/D/YYYY h:m:s) it can't fit in the format i defined.

Any idea? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Dates have no format. They are binary values, just like integers. Simple delete that code and just use `var currentDate=DateTime.Now`. Formats are used only when creating a string from a value or parsing a string into a value

Comment: What you're doing is pointless... as Panagiotis mentions - DateTime does not have a format. Just use `DateTime.Now` then format how you like  when displaying the date.

Comment: `Datetime currentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` if you insist on `ToString` / `Parse`

Comment: Perhaps the *real* question is how to display dates in your form, report, web page, file  or whatever you use to display the dates? All reporting tools allow setting a format or culture, all .NET stacks (Winforms, WPF, WebForms, MVC, etc) allow setting a format during binding. Data Annotation attributes allow you to specify a display format. In the worst case you can use `String.Format()` to display the data the way you want.

Comment: what you need is `String currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString( "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. Remember dd and yyyy are case sensitive

Comment: Updated my question with more information about what led me try to format every system datetime in that format.

Comment: @PythagorasDoe, then you need a string and not DateTime. DateTime doesn't hold any format

Comment: Use this format (note the capitals): `dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss'

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the same format string and culture in every place where you convert the `DateTime` to string as well. In your sample code, you're doing

```
DateTime.Now.ToString()
```

This uses the default culture for the thread, and the default format. Unless assigned otherwise, the thread is probably using the local culture info. Instead, you would want to use the same format and the invariant culture:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(note the lowercase "dd". "DD" is not a valid format specifier for date times; these things are case sensitive. Also note the "HH", which gives a 24-hour value, rather than 12-hour)

In practice, just using the invariant culture should be enough for persistence. Cultures already include default datetime formats, so unless you have  a specific need to use a different format, why not use the default?

Also note that `DateTime` *doesn't have a format*. The format only comes into play when you convert from or to a string. That is the place where you need to ensure the same culture and format is used for both sides of the operation (and that's why for persistence, especially for data shared between different users or computers, you generally want to use the invariant culture).

Comment: Hey Luuan! I updated my question with more information about what led me try to format every system datettime in that format.

Comment: @PythagorasDoe The core of the problem is still the same - you must change the way the date times are *written*. There's nothing you can fix on the reading end.

Answer (score 0):

If you need

> to make sure my program run's in **every system**, regardless the system datetime.now

you can adapt *international standard* for this, say, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

In order to validate the `DateTime`, *regular expressions* like you have are not enough (just imagine *leap years*), but `TryParse` does it job:

```
 string source = "2019-09-26T23:45:59";

 // Either current culture date and time format or ISO
 bool isValid = DateTime.TryParse(
   source, 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
   DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
   out var _date);
```

Or if you want to be more restrictive use `TryParseExact`:

```
// ISO only
bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
  source, 
 "s",
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
  DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
  out var _date);
```

If you want to represent `DateTime.Now` in **ISO 8601**, add `"s"` standard format string:

```
 string dateAsString = DateTime.Now.ToString("s");
```

Alas, you can provide a bunch of formats which are able to cope with any date and time formats; a classical example of *ambiguous date* is

```
 01/02/03 - 01 Feb 2003 (Russia)
 01/02/03 - 02 Jan 2003 (USA)
 01/02/03 - 03 Feb 2001 (China)
```

You can *alleviate* the problem, while providing *several* `formats`:

```
 // Here we try to support 4 formats (note different delimeters)
 string[] formats = new string[] {
   "s",                            // try ISO first
   "dd'.'MM'.'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss",  // if failed try Russian
   "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss",  // on error have a look at USA
   "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss",  // the last hope is Chinese
 };

 bool isValid = DateTime.TryParse(
   source, 
   formats,
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
   DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
   out var date);
```